# Как сделать search dialog c помощью ActionBArSherlock?

Tags: actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android, java

Добрый день!
Делал все по [статье от гугла](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), но использовал ActionbarSherlock c его реализацией SearchView, но запросы не приходят SearchActivity.( я знаю, что ABS для версии 3.0 использует стандартный ActionBar, а для младших использует свою реализацию)
Манифест проверил на много раз, перелопатил кучу ссылок по этому запросу, но ничего не решилось. Может кто из вас знает в чем может быть проблема.  Запрос отправляется только, когда нажимаешь на кнопку "enter" на клавиатуре, а хотелось бы, чтобы все работало аналогично живому поиску, как только начал вводить, сразу пошел поиск.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="ru.ex.Interface"
              android:versionCode="45"
              android:versionName="2.2.1b"
              android:installLocation="auto"
            >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

        <application
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Custom"

                >

            <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value=".SearchActivity"/>

            <activity
                    android:name=".SearchActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:parentActivityName=".MainFragmentActivity"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    >
                <!-- This intent-filter identifies this activity as "searchable" -->

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>

                <!-- This metadata entry provides further configuration details for searches -->
                <!-- that are handled by this activity. -->

                <meta-data
                        android:name="android.app.searchable"
                        android:resource="@xml/search_config" />

            </activity>

            <activity
                    android:name=".MainFragmentActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:launchMode="singleTask"
                    >

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Создание меню**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.serch_menu, menu);            
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu).getActionView();            
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));            
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
        return true;
    }
```

**SearchActivity.java**

```
public class SearchActivity extends CustomMenuFragmentActivity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle save)
    {
        super.onCreate(save);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_page);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            goSearch(query);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void goSearch(final String s)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблеме решена следующим образом. Все активити в приложении наследуются от одного базового. 
Создан собственный фрагмент, который осуществляет поиск. В базовом активити, когда начинается ввод в поисковую строку, срабатывает событие изменения текста, фрагмент добавляется в нужное место и отображает результаты.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        if (null != searchView ) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        }
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                switchSearchQuery(query);
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                switchSearchQuery(query);
                return true;
            }
        };
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    }
```

Comment: а от куда метод switchSearchQuery?

Comment: это мой метод, я там для разных страниц курсор подменяю



   private void switchSearchQuery(String query) {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(Constants.EXTRA_FILTER, query);

                mf.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundle, mf);
    }

Comment: так тогда же теряется весь смысл search dilog :)

Comment: как? почему?

Answer (score 0):

Отличная [либа](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-CollapsibleSearchMenu), да еще и с 2.1 работает.

Comment: либа не очень понравилась, такое решение я и сам могу написать. Падает, если не отправить TextWatcher.